# PictureBox.BackgroundImageLayout change fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, layout, picturebox

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and writing a simple project in c#. I have a picture box and two buttons. When one button is pressed, the image in picture box is changed, but I cannot change the background image layout property. In button callback is something like:

```
pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("test.jpg");  
pictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

The image is changed, but it is not stretched over picture box. In fact, only part of the image that fits in picture box is shown.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE

It was my mistake. The call in button callback was actually:

`pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("test.jpg");

pictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;`

instead of upper statement.

Comment: try calling `pictureBox1.Refresh();`

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:/elefent.jpg");      
}
```

The pictureBox layout changed when I used:

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enlarge and fit the image within the control's client rectangle, set the `BackgroundImageLayout` to `ImageLayout.Zoom`

```
pictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
```

You could also try `SizeMode` property

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

Comment: Thank You for Your brief reply. However, no matter what ImageLayout I choose, nothing changes. The image is actually much larger than the picture box, so I see only part of it. Stretch should be the proper layout.

Comment: @user2546901 - see my edit. I stressing zoom because it will maintain the size ratio

Answer (score -1):

After struggling with this for a few days, This is the only correct answer:

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

This is not right:

<strike>pictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;</strike>